# What does the snake on the body of Srinathji signify?

Tags: krishna, temple

[image]

The enclosed image of [Srinathji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrinathji) shows a snake around His body which normally remains hidden under clothes.

What does this snake signify? Please cite proper sources.

Comment: @The Destroyer I think this and every other idol of Sri Krishna symbolises some yogic process. The snake seemsmsymbolic of kundalini, the flute of NAda, the thribhanga the breaking of three granthis and so on.*